# How do I sort two glossaries (list of acronyms and list of symbols) differently?

Tags: glossaries, sorting

I use the `glossaries` package to create a list of acronyms as well as a list of symbols.

```
\usepackage[acronym,style=long]{glossaries}
```

For the list of symbols the standard-glossary is used.

Now I want to sort the list of acronyms alphabetically (`sort=standard`), but the list of symbols in order of appearance (`sort=def`). How do I do that?

I use MikTeX 2.9 with TeXnicCenter 2 (beta) on Windows 7. My project includes the `hyperref` package.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 10):

**Update**:

As from `glossaries` version 4.04 (which I've just uploaded to CTAN) there are now three options for generating glossaries:

1. Using TeX to sort the glossaries (new).
2. Using `makeindex` to sort the glossaries.
3. Using `xindy` to sort the glossaries.

The options 2 and 3 still can't use independent sort methods for different glossaries, but the new option can:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronyms]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newacronym{cd}{CD}{covariant derivative}
\newacronym{gr}{GR}{general relativity}
\newacronym{pnd}{PND}{principle null direction}

\newglossaryentry{vfield}{
  name={\ensuremath{A^a}},
  description={Some vector field}
}

\newglossaryentry{manifold}{
  name={\ensuremath{\mathcal{M}}},
  description={Some manifold}
}

\begin{document}

Einstein developed the theory of \gls{gr}. Take the \gls{cd} and
apply it on the \glspl{pnd}. We define \gls[format=textbf]{manifold} to be some
manifold.

\clearpage

\gls[format=textbf]{vfield} is some vector field on \gls{manifold}
that has nothing to do with the \glspl{pnd}.

\printnoidxglossary[type=acronym,sort=letter]

\printnoidxglossary[sort=use]

\end{document}
```

This only requires two LaTeX runs (no need to use `xindy` or `makeindex`). The list of acronyms is sorted by letter (using `datatool`'s `\dtlletterindexcompare` handler) and the main glossary is sorted according to use. Other sort options are: `word` (word ordering using `datatool`'s `\dtlwordindexcompare` handler), `def` (order of definition), `case` (case-sensitive using `datatool`'s `\dtlcompare` handler) and `nocase` (case-insensitive using `datatool`'s `\dtlicompare` handler).

Page 1:

[image: Image of page 1]

Page 2:

[image: Image of page 2]

Main drawbacks:

- Sorting is slower than when using `makeindex` / `xindy` (except for the `use` method, which doesn't require any sorting).
- Consecutive locations won't be turned into a range (although it's possible to redefine the macro that displays the location list).
- Entries must be defined before the start of the `document` environment.

**Solution using `datagidx`:**

Here's my original solution using `datagidx` (part of the [datatool bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datagidx}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newgidx{acronym}{Acronyms}
\newgidx{symbol}{Symbols}

\DTLgidxSetDefaultDB{acronym}

\newacro{html}{hypertext markup language}
\newacro{css}{cascading style sheet}
\newacro{xml}{extensible markup language}

\DTLgidxSetDefaultDB{symbol}

\newterm[description={sample 1}]{B}
\newterm[description={sample 2}]{X}
\newterm[description={sample 3}]{A}
\newterm[description={sample 4}]{C}

\begin{document}

\gls{B}, \gls{X}, \gls{C}, \gls{A}.

\acr{xml}, \acr{html}, \acr{css}.

% default sort is alphabetical
\printterms[database=acronym,columns=1,style=align]

% sort by definition (i.e. don't sort)

\printterms[database=symbol,sort={},columns=1,style=align]

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Image of result]

Comment: I am sorry, but when should I use `option 1` or `option 2` for `glossaries` package? I am totally confused. In other words, should I use `option 1` if I want more control on the way the glossary is printed?

Comment: It depends what kind of control you want. The three options govern the way the entries are sorted and collated. The `use` and `def` settings for options 2 and 3 just override the default setting of the `sort` key so that it has a numerical value. In the case of option 1, the `def` and `use` settings don't actually do any sorting. If you want to sort according to a different alphabet, then `xindy` (option 3) is best.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks!
I actually just found a way to do that thing with the glossaries package. It is possible, since I define a command for all my symbols anyway...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[acronym,style=long,sanitize={sort=false}]{glossaries}   % acronyms and list of symbols
\makeglossaries

% sort symbol index in order of appearance
% warning: this is only valid for less than 1000 pages!
\makeatletter
\def\three@digits#1{\ifnum#1<100 0\ifnum#1<10 0\fi\fi\number#1}

% \nomNoPrint declares a new glossary entry
\newcommand{\nomNoPrint}[3]{\newglossaryentry{#1}{
    name={#2},
    symbol={#2},
    description={#3},
    sort={A\three@digits{\value{page}}}
    }\glsadd[format=hyperbf]{#1}}   
\makeatother

% \nom declares the entry and prints the symbol
\newcommand{\nom}[3]{\nomNoPrint{#1}{#2}{#3}#2}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% define some acronyms
\newacronym{cd}{CD}{covariant derivative}
\newacronym{pnd}{PND}{principle null direction}
\newacronym{gr}{GR}{general relativity}

% define some symbols
\newcommand{\manifoldDNA}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{M}}} % the do-not-add definition
\newcommand{\manifold}{\glsadd{manifold}\manifoldDNA}

\newcommand{\vfieldDNA}{\ensuremath{A^a}}
\newcommand{\vfield}{\glsadd{vfield}\vfieldDNA}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

Einstein developed the theory of \gls{gr}. Take the \gls{cd} and apply it on the \glspl{pnd}. We define
\nom{manifold}{\manifoldDNA}{Some manifold}\ 
to be some manifold.

\clearpage

\nom{vfield}{\vfieldDNA}{Some vector field} is some vector field on \manifold\ that has nothing to do with the \glspl{pnd}.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\printglossary

\end{document}
```

It then looks like this:

[image]

It is not as nice as the other approach, because one has to define the `\manifoldDNA` and `\vfieldDNA` commands to avoid that the same pagenumber is printed twice in the glossary (once normal and once boldtype).